# Not able to link gcc against libbluetooth library

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth, bluez

I am using BlueZ library for developing bluetooth based application for linux using C. I am trying to link libbluetooth-dev to my C file but it is not working.

```sh
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libbluetooth-dev
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My project directory is bluez-5.45, i am trying to build the project from this folder and added my .C file in this main folder

I installed libbluetooth-dev library and tryed that linking but not able to do that.
Command for linking: 
`gcc -o output myfile.c -libbluetooth`

please let me know the mistake done by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "lib" is implied, so link against "bluetooth" instead of "libbluetooth":

```sh
$ gcc -o output myfile.c -lbluetooth
```